# How to remove parent control without deleting its children in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, composite-controls

I want to remove parent control (which is span in this case) without deleting its children controls from container. how can I accomplish this in asp.net c#?

you can see the code here: http://pastebin.com/9NiriWXN

Note: I can easily find the "newsright" control and return its parent (which is span in this case)

Comment: Maybe just reassign all children to other control at first, then delete span control.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get the children first and the parent of the parent control and then add the children back to the parent of the parent control.

Comment: Control newsControl = FindChildControl(this, "newsright");
Control tempControl = newsControl;
Control grand = newsControl.Parent.Parent;
int indexatnewparent = newsControl.Parent.Parent.Controls.IndexOf(newsControl.Parent);
grand.Controls.RemoveAt(indexatnewparent);
grand.Controls.AddAt(indexatnewparent, tempControl);

Comment: The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases. i got this message since this code is in On_Load()